# Kodein Injecting into WorkManager

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kodein

I'm new to android development, i need to inject WorkManager for using kodein but i don't know where to start it

this is how to inject activities

```
class MyActivity : Activity(), KodeinAware {

override val kodein by kodein() 

val ds: DataSource by instance()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    ds.connect() 
    /* ... */
   }

}
```

this is my worker i need to get the instance of Appdatabase for using kodein but it didn't work for me

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, params), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by kodein()


    private val db: AppDatabase by instance()

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(IO) {
        try {
            //do the work
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.retry()
          }
       }

   }
```

Binding the AppDatabase

```
class AppBase : Application(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
    import(androidXModule(this@AppBase))
    bind() from singleton { AppDatabase.getInstance(instance())}
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? How did you bind AppDatabase?

Comment: i'm updated the question look it back

Answer (score 3):

Not sure your code even compiles...

Regarding to your Worker class:

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, params), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by kodein()
    // ...
}
```

As far as I saw, there is no such method as `kodein()` for the `CoroutineWorker`. Thus, this is not working. But, as you have a `Context`, you could use the following code to get your `Kodein` container:

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, params), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by kodein { context }
    // ...
}
```

Let us know if this works for you. (Otherwise post the error you get).

Comment: also you could use `override val kodein: Kodein by closestKodein { context }`

Comment: Yes but this one calls the one I’d put in my answer. Also it’s in deprecation circle, thus it will be remove soon